# Use v-for in Templates (Vue-Tables-2)

Tags: vue.js, templates, axios, vue-tables-2

I would like to display axios data in my datatables being that they have a dynamic key I would like to create a template

Data Set :
`"environment": "production", "version": "5.6", "apache_version": "3.2.1"`

My Vue.js :

```
    new Vue({
    el: "#info",
    mounted() {
        this.getInfo()
    },
    methods: {
        getInfo() {
            axios
            .get("http://localhost:8080/info")
            .then(response => {
                this.info = response.data
            })
        },
    },
    data: {
        selectedRow: [],
        columns: ['name','value'],
        rows : [],
        options: {
            headings: {
                name: 'Info',
                value: 'Value'
            },
            sortable: ['name','value'],
            filterByColumn: true,
        },
    },
});
```

My HTML :

```
<div id="info" v-cloack>
    <v-client-table :data="rows" :columns="columns" :options="options">
        <template slot="name" scope="props">
            <div v-for="(value, name) in info">
                <p>{{ props.rows.name }}</p>
            </div>
        </template>
        <template slot="value" scope="props">
            <div v-for="(value, name) in info">
                <p>{{ props.rows.value }}</p>
            </div>
        </template>
    </v-client-table>
</div>
```

In order to display in the name column : environment, version, apache_version 
And in the value column display : production, 5.6 , 3.2.1

Thanks !

Comment: Can you cooperate what the issue is exactly any errors, what's happening?

Comment: I have my data in my response but when i want to print this in table is writting 'No match records'

Comment: Yes can you show us a sample of that data, you are not setting columns anywhere

Comment: It is a part of a data : `{
 "environment": "production",
 "version": "5.6",
 "apache_version": "3.2.1",
 "apt_dist_updates": 328,
 "apt_has_dist_updates": false,
 "apt_has_updates": true
}` the key is always different so I have a problem with the declaration of the columns

Comment: You can create a computed property that loops on your data and returns the columns by looping on the key and the value of each property in your object. I would write it for you but idk the correct format you need the columns in, it depends on that component you have and how it takes the data. If you have a simple working example on a different that i can maybe help

Comment: For my column i want to have key in column name and value in column value like this: `{ "name":"environment", "value":"production", "name":"version", "value":"5.6", "name":"apache_version", "value":"3.2.1", "name": "apt_dist_updates", "value": 328, "name": "apt_has_dist_updates", "value": false, "name": "apt_has_updates", "value":true}` , and thanks for your help !

Comment: I have edited my answer showing you the computed property i did and what it returns, this is a demo of how you can loop into the data you have but you can change it to your liking bcz the object you sent me is not a valid object since theres different values for each key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This inside axios does not have access to the component you should do as follows:

```
 new Vue({
    el: "#info",
    mounted() {
        this.getInfo()
    },
    methods: {
        getInfo() {
            let vm = this;
            axios
            .get("http://localhost:8080/info")
            .then(response => {
                vm.info = response.data
            })
        },
    },
    data: {
        selectedRow: [],
        columns: ['name','value'],
        rows : [],
        info: [],
        options: {
            headings: {
                name: 'Info',
                value: 'Value'
            },
            sortable: ['name','value'],
            filterByColumn: true,
        },
    },
    computed: {
        formattedColumns() {
            let columns = [];
            for (const key in this.info) {
                let column = {};
                column.name = key;
                column.value = this.info[key];
                columns.push(column);
            }
            return columns;
        }
    }
});
```

This computed property returns something like this :

```
[{name: "environment", value: "production"},{name: "version", value: "5.6"..}]
```

You can sure change it to your liking and to what is needed

Comment: I get the data in my response but in the table it says "No matching records"

Comment: It works however I was mistaken it was not columns that should get the data but rows because it is rows that contains the data to display, thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Girl Codes for helping me to display with vue-tables-2 data with a dynamic key you must add this property in vue.js :

```
el: "#info",
mounted() {
    this.getInfo()  
},
methods: {
    getInfo() {
        axios
        .get("http://localhost:8080/info")
        .then(response => {
            this.rows = response.data
        })
    },
},
data: {
    columns: ['name','value'],
    options: {
        headings: {
            name: 'Info',
            value: 'Value'
        },
        sortable: ['name','value'],
        filterByColumn: true,
    },
},
computed: {
    formattedRows() {
        let rows = [];
        for (const key in this.rows) {
            let row = {};
            row.name = key;
            row.value = this.rows[key];
            rows.push(row);
        }
        return rows;
    }
}
```

Comment: And in html : `<div id="info" v-cloack> <v-client-table :data="formattedRows" :columns="columns" :options="options"> </v-client-table> </div>`